# Neoload What does it mean "%" in a comparison report of both Scenario and how calculate the %?

Tags: performance, comparison, load-testing, stress-testing, neoload

I have a Question what does it mean % in a comparison report generate from neoload ,how calculate to get % result of comparison on both Scenario and what its the importance on the report?
Check out the Image please [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU8dJ.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tIam.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '%' represents the percentage difference between the 2 test runs that have been executed. In your case, it is the percentage difference between test run B and test run C. In the images that showcases Avg %, Max % and Duration, the representation is difference in the response times between Run B and Run C.

Mathematically,

`Avg % or Max % or Duration % = ((Value for Run C - Value for Run B)/Value for Run B) * 100;`

Generically,

`Percentage difference = ((Value of Second Run - Value of First Run)/Value of First Run) * 100`

---

Example

Avg:

`((112.2-68.9)/68.9)*100 ~ +63%`

Max:

`((112.4-118.6)/112.4)*100 ~ -5.2%`

Duration:

`((0.257-0.452)/0.452)*100 ~ -43.1%`

The color representation for positive values are red and negative values are green in this case because response times are better if the value is less. This representation is bound to vary for values such as Hits, Throughput etc.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.